# Map other variable to fill in R ggridges

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges, ridgeline-plot

I would like to create `geom_density_ridges_gradient` plot, but **use different fill then x variable**. Is it possible?
I have not seen any example on internet

**Example of plot:**

The only difference, I would like to map different variable to fill. It could be speed, compared to speed limit
[image]

**Example data:**

```
df <- data.frame(
    road = c('a', 'b'),
    speed = runif(100, 1, 100)
  ) %>%
  mutate(limit = ifelse(road == 'a', 50, 30),
         overlimit = speed - limit)
```

**What works:**

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = speed, y = road,  fill = stat(x))) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient()
```

**What does not work:**

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = speed, y = road,  fill = overlimit)) +
  geom_density_ridges_gradient()
```

[image]

Error message:

> ```
> The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: fill
> i This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the correct grouping structure in the data.
> i Did you forget to specify a `group` aesthetic or to convert a numerical variable into a
>   factor?
> ```

Comment: So, if I could better understand: Do you want to plots which share the same independent  variables, but to have multiple plots to represent multiple ```fill``` variables?